# Apex CPU time limid exceed

Tags: salesforce

I am calling an API to get the codes and create a file of codes, I can call the API and get the response but when I am processing the response it's giving me the Apex CPU time limit exceeded.
The reason is response data is too big.
I am still confused with the solution that is suitable for this.

Comment: Check [Salesforce SE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com), lots of Q&As on this topic

Comment: Post your code or details of the API you're calling? Maybe there's a way to call it with some pagination, more chunks of response with less rows in each chunk. Maybe your code could use some optimisations we can suggest. Maybe you could use an apex batch job or Continuation pattern. Maybe nothing can be done server-side and you could consider processing in JavaScript (yuck but free from governor limits)